# How to pass value to modal using React.js?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, json

I have a table that returns data after a `.data.map()..` as shown below:

```
{this.state.data.map((item, i) => { 
   return (div>
              <tr>
                  <td>{item.id}</td>
                  <td>{item.name}</td>
                  <td>{item.symbol}</td>
```

And a `<td>` in the same `<table>` and `<tr>` above that displays my modal with the below code:

```
<td>
    <div>
        <a className="btn" href="#open-modal" title="More Details"></a>
        <div id="open-modal" className="modal-window">
        <div>
          <a href={url} title="Close" className="modal-close">❌</a>
          <div>Update Details</div>
            <label>{item.id}</label> //WHERE I WANT TO DISPLAY MY ID
        </div><a href={url}></a></div>
    </div>
</td>
```

Now when I want to display the `item.id` of each particular row after opening the modal, it returns the `item.id` of only 1 item in the array and not the actual `item.id`.

So the `item.id` in `<td>` is different from the `item.id` in the modal. It keeps returning the same `item.id` for every row I click on. How can I have these 2 have the same value?

Comment: you need to have one state which holds the selected item . And use this state's value inside your modal's content . `{this.state.selectedItem.id}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The modal only reference to your last id at the time you rendered it**

I would suggest you have a state to store your `id` and render it when you open your modal.

Something like:

```
const [selectedId, setSelectedId] = useState();

<td>
    <div>
        <a
          className="btn"
          onClick={() => setSelectedId(item.id)}
          href="#open-modal" title="More Details"
        ></a>
        <div id="open-modal" className="modal-window">
        <div>
          <a href={url} title="Close" className="modal-close">❌</a>
          <div>Update Details</div>
            <label>{selectedId}</label>
        </div><a href={url}></a></div>
    </div>
</td>
```

---

The  looks scary though.